# Calling a macro to a different workbook python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

so I'm trying to make my life a bit easier by have Python + Excel automate some of the things I need to do for reports. I have created an Excel workbook (macro enabled) that's just dedicated to macros. For example, when I press ctrl+R, it removes any spaces and parenthesis's that I do not want for reports. My question is how can open the macro workbook then open the other reports that I need and use the macro.

This is my current code:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.books.open(r'macrofile.xlsb', r'reportthatneedswork.csv')
macroname = wb.macro('MacroName')
macroname()
```

It is only opening the macro workbook but not the other and does not do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an Excel macro via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)

Comment: @itprorh66 it doesn't. I'm trying to do this within xlwings if possible

Comment: Does this [How do I call an Excel macro from Python using xlwings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308455/how-do-i-call-an-excel-macro-from-python-using-xlwings) answer your question?

Comment: @itprorh66 it helps a little, I'm still struggling on reading another sheet/book and calling that macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on using this frequently I would rewrite the macro code in python+xlwings. This removes the issue of running things from other workbooks and will let you run it on multiple files at once by just adding looping logic:

### macro.py

```
import os
import sys
import xlwings as xw
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def python_macro(wb_path, app):
    #Optionally verify that files are all xls*, csv, or directory files

    wb = app.books.open(wb_path)
    sheet = wb.sheets.active
    
    #Rewrite macro in python+xlwings below
    print(sheet.range('A1').value)


with xw.App() as app:    
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        path = join(os.getcwd(), arg)
            
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            #Optionally process further subdirectories
                
            files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

            for file in files:
                python_macro(file, app)

        elif os.path.isfile(path):
            python_macro(path, app)
```

Save the file in the same directory as the report files and running it would look like this:

`python macro.py reportthatneedswork.csv anotherreport.csv report-sub-dir`

---

From what I could find, there isn't really a way to execute external workbook macros with xlwings. The closest thing I found was using win32com to extract and move over the vb script then you could use xlwing to open it an run the macro. **However**, this is particularly overkill for your scenario. It will be much easier to deal with if you just rewrite the macro in python.

[Read VBA from workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288193/8328420) and then ['inject' it into another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257036/8328420).